# Conversion of a Web application from vs2008 to vs2010?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, internet-explorer

I have a web application which was working well until I converted it from vs2008 to vs2010.
It has to support IE6 .I am using some jquery and javascript in my application.
so when I first run the web application in vs2010 it was fine ,except it popped up a message stating that change the following setting in IE so I changed the settings under Internet Options > Advanced > cleared  the disable script debugging option.

The following error is popped up in a message box after I change the above settings in IE6.

**Error:**

```
A runtime Error has occured.
Do you wih to debug ?

Line:2
Error:syntax error
```

I have various confirmation boxes generated from javascript and jquery in the application.If I disable that option in IE ,I am unable to see those boxes now.

Is it some thing with the conversion from vs2008 and vs2010 or is it some thing with IE.I completely lost track here I think, I would appreciate if someone can guide me .

Comment: Is this a javascript error ? and this is happens on an update panel ?

Comment: Yes its a java script error .And i am not using any update panels.

Comment: What happens when you click "yes" ?

Comment: @MalcolmFrexner :When i click yes the application behaves in normal way .i.e i get to redirected where i am supposed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a wild guess here but you might want to check your doctype declaration.  I think that VS 2008 uses 
`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

and vs 2010 uses the html5 declaration standard.  I'm thinking that the doctype may be causing IE to run differently, e.g. not in quirks mode.

Comment: I think thats what it shows error for me ..how do i change that ?

Comment: In VS go to Tools - Options - HTML/XML - Format
At the top top you have "Apply Automatic Formatting" section.
Uncheck the tow checkboxes, so the VS doesn't format your HTML.  Hopefully that helps.